# device_lib.list_local_devices() can't find my gtx 960 gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just run the code of `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb`, but i get an error as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Project/PY/Tensorflow/Official/RNN/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py", line 502, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "F:/Project/PY/Tensorflow/Official/RNN/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py", line 429, in main
    % (len(gpus), FLAGS.num_gpus))
ValueError: Your machine has only 0 gpus which is less than the requested --num_gpus=1.
```

---

Then I learn that `device_lib.list_local_devices()` returns nothing.

I do have a gpu of gtx 960m, why did  `device_lib.list_local_devices()` not recognize my device?!

Comment: Did you build tensorflow from source or installed from repo?

Comment: thanks for your answer. my environment is win10 & tensorflow 1.3. well, i used pip to install tensorflow. there is something to do with the way i installed tensorflow?

Comment: You have to install `tensorflow-gpu` for GPU compatibility. If it's still not showing up, guarantee you have CUDA & cuDNN installed and test if your Nvidia card is showing up in the [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz).

Comment: thanks to  Tiago Vieira, i have uninstalled tensorflow, and install the tensorflow-gpu. yeah, device_lib.list_local_devices() got my device, but i got new problem as follow: Op type not registered 'CudnnRNNParamsSize' in binary running on *. btw: thanks to jHilscher, are you admin?